# Cordova encrypt source code

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I have project in Phonegap / Cordova and i need secrecy in source-code. Is there any way to encrypt my source code for anyone don't extract the APK file in android?

I saw a plugin [Cordova crypt file plugin](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file), but it does not work, it is out of date and not have suport, and, when i installed, my javascript code does not work.

I need an efficient alternative solution. What is recommended?

Comment: Over a year later, I've tried the plugin mentioned in the post on an android project - and seems to work well. The plugin  was last updated in Oct 2016, and devs seem to have closed issues raised..

Comment: anyone checking this page try this one [cordova-plugin-crypto-file](https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file) works with webview

Answer (score 3):

**Best solutions for Obfuscation encryption:**

[jscrambler](http://jscrambler.com) and [Javascript Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com)

> Decryption performed tests and they did well. Much of the code has not
>   been decrypted and organized completely, which brought more security.
>
> I recommend joining all the javascript code in just one file and then
>   encrypt it.

**Sites used to try decrypt:**

[ddecode.com/hexdecoder](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) and [dcode.fr/javascript-unobfuscator](http://www.dcode.fr/javascript-unobfuscator)

Comment: While this makes it a little bit harder, it is not a safe solution at all - it is always easily possible to revert this method.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice workaround here

[Encrypt Source Files](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/386/how-to-encrypt-protect-the-source-code-of-an-android-cordova-app)

All you need to do is add:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypt-file

and as soon as you run:

cordova build android

or

cordova build android --prod --release

it will be encrypted.

To verify, try extracting the apk file using any archive utility tool and open the source file, you will see it encrypted

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine...
You can follow below step:
1.Add source at **root www** folder.
2.Add cordova plugin add -> **cordova-plugin-crypt-file**
3.Execute below command:
  **cordova build**

Its encrypt the root **www** folder to **{project_name}\platforms\android\assets\www**.

Answer (score -1):

This is the Best plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap app source code security.
try this plugin: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypt-file`

Official Repo: [enter link description here](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file.git)

Answer (score -3):

To encrypt use the cordova command line (cli):

```
cordova build android
```

And not encrypt if you are using the command run android or emulate android.